# Does YouCompleteme only works using std::function? Else won't have function and parameter tips

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I compiled YouCompleteMe using the full installation guide, and with default .ycm_extra_conf.py loaded. However, when I tried to create a .cpp file and find functions, e.g. strcpy, will only tips when typing std:: even I have put "using namespace std;" in code.

I don't understand why the standard library functions will not auto complete. Does anyone know what I have be missing?
I also attached my YcmDebugInfo.
Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Buh4n.png)
YcmDebugInfo

Answer (score 0):

It works fine after setting the auto trigger as below:

```
let g:ycm_auto_trigger=1
let g:ycm_semantic_triggers = {
\'c' : ['->', '    ', '.', ' ', '(', '[', '&'],
\'cpp,objcpp' : ['->', '.', ' ', '(', '[', '&', '::'],
\'perl' : ['->', '::', ' '],
\'php' : ['->', '::', '.'],
\'cs,java,javascript,d,vim,python,perl6,scala,vb,elixir,go' : ['.'],
\'ruby' : ['.', '::'],
\'lua' : ['.', ':'],
\'scss,css': [ 're!^\s{2,4}', 're!:\s+' ],
\'html': ['<', '"', '</', ' '],
\'javascript': ['.', 're!(?=[a-zA-Z]{3,4})'],
\}
```